# How to chop up a big, slow PostgreSQL query into smaller queries then merge?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, knex.js

For the sake of optimizations, we've taken a big, slow query of ours and chopped it up into smaller queries so that overloaded nodes can offset to other nodes on the server. We then merge the results of the queries into a single results list, and return that to the frontend gridview for display. We can sort and even filter resulting data in the merged list by using Node.js functions like `.sort((a, b) => { ... })`.

The problem? **Pagination**. How would you retain accurate sorting and filtering with this method when your data is also paginated?

E.g. if I have some names in the database that get displayed on the frontend:

```
Page 1:
Sally
Bob
Paul

Page 2:
Hanna
Mo
Carl

Page 3:
Alex
Zoe
Sara
```

And I have three names per page, sorting with our current method would do this:

```
Page 1:
Bob
Paul
Sally

Page 2:
Carl
Hanna
Mo

Page 3:
Alex
Sara
Zoe
```

Where what we need is this:

```
Page 1:
Alex
Bob
Carl

Page 2:
Hanna
Mo
Paul

Page 3:
Sally
Sara
Zoe
```

Our queries and databases are all pretty complicated so I can't really show any specific examples - that's okay though, I'm only looking for a high-level answer here. I don't need specifics.

For reference we use JavaScript, Node.js, Postgres, and use a combination of knex and sequelize.

EDIT: I'm also open to better methods to optimize. We've tried adding indexes and have experimented between different types of joins and using subqueries instead (and vise versa).

Comment: Without details about the data and query, we can't offer optimizations.

Comment: Could you us the original (large) query, the new small queries, your datamodel and the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) on all these queries? Without that information, we're basically blind and can't help you.